# How to route a React-Redux app?

Tags: javascript, react-router, react-router-dom

I have started to create a simple `React-Redux` app following a tutorial. But since then router system of React has changed and I cant figure how to use routes correctly.

My `index.js` file consists of:

```
import App from "./containers/App"

render(

    <Provider store={store}>
          <App />
    </Provider>
 ,
    window.document.getElementById('app'));
```

And then in `containers/App.js`

```
    ...
    import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
    import {Header} from '../components/Header';
    ...


    class App extends React.Component {

      render() {
        return (
          <Router>
          <div className="container">
            <Header/>
            <Main changeUsername={() => this.props.setName("Anna")}/>

            <User username={this.props.user.name}/>

          </div>
        </Router>
        );
      }
    }
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    user: state.user,
    math: state.math
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    setName: (name) => {
      dispatch(setName(name));
    },

  };
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

and problem comes from components/Header.js

```
import { Link} from 'react-router-dom'
const Header = (props) => {
    return (

        <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <Link className="nav-link" to="/">Spider</Link>
          <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>

          <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul className="navbar-nav mr-auto">
              <li className="nav-item" activeClassName={"active"}>
                <Link className="nav-link"  to="/home">Home</Link>
              </li>
              <li className="nav-item"  activeClassName={"active"}>
                <Link className="nav-link" to="{user/${user.id}}">User</Link>
              </li>

            </ul>

          </div>
        </nav>

    );
}

export default Header
```

The console shows the error:

```
Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.
    in App (created by Connect(App))
    in Connect(App)
    in Provider
```

How can I fix it ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the way you are importing `Header` component. You exported it as a default and but you are importing it a named import here

```
import {Header} from '../components/Header';
```

Change the import to

```
import Header from '../components/Header';
```

or change the export in Header component to

```
export { Header }
```

Apart from this, you need to fix other small issues as well

**First:**

```
 <Link className="nav-link" to="{user/${user.id}}">User</Link>
```

should be

```
<Link className="nav-link" to=`{user/${user.id}}`>User</Link>
```

**Second:**

You need to use withRouter with Header since its not connected to Route directly

You could do that like

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router'
const withHeader = withRouter(Header)
export {withHeader as Header}
```

or

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router'
export default withRouter(Header)
```

depending on how you import it

Comment: Also please add how have you configured your `Routes` if you are facing any issues with it as well

Comment: thanks .. it was an export problem. but I am confused ? am I supposed to use react-router or react-router-dom ?

Comment: You may need to use a combination of the two

Comment: I cant manage to get props of userlink can you help me ? can we chat somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you forgot to add `export default App` in `containers/App.js`.

Try importing Header component like `import Header from '../components/Header'`

Comment: I have added react-redux connector , I have shortened the code while pasting.